# Pre-sorting a DataGrid in WPF according to localized sort order

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF4 `DataGrid` (the one that's included with WPF4) with columns 'Surname', 'First Names' etc. When the user clicks a column header, for example 'Surname', everything gets sorted in the right order according to my culture settings, e.g:

```
Anderson
Rockford
Ångström
```

I want the 'Surname' column to be pre-sorted, so I've added

```
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SurName" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
```

just like in the answer to the [Pre-sorting a DataGrid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627149/pre-sorting-a-datagrid-in-wpf) question. The problem is, that WPF now uses a different sort order where 'Å' is sorted like 'A' (I guess that's a US sort order):

```
Andersson
Ångström
Rockford
```

Manually clicking the 'Surname' header re-sorts the names, this time according to my culture settings.

How do I tell WPF to use the current culture setting when pre-sorting the DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the CollectionViewSource's Culture property? Something like (drycoded) *Edited per your comment*:

```
... in your namespaces
xmlns:glob="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
....


<CollectionViewSource Culture="{x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SurName" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

I'm not sure why the CollectionViewSource wouldn't use the same culture by default, but if it's not this should be the property that fixes it for you.

See also this article on how binding seems to use the wrong culture when the target is a string, perhaps it can shed some light for you: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/02/22/wpf-data-binding-cheat-sheet-update-the-internationalization-fix.aspx

Or this question: [WPF XAML Bindings and CurrentCulture Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991526/wpf-xaml-bindings-and-currentculture-display)

Comment: `Culture="{x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}"` works (rather than `...CurrentUICulture` for some reason), thx! Not really sure why I need it though, since I also use the `OverrideMetadata` fix as described in your cheat sheet link.