# ColumnHeader arrows not reflected when sorting a DataGrid in XAML

Tags: .net, sorting, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with some sorting defined in XAML like so:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="DefaultSort" Source="{Binding SearchResults}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ExternalOrgNo" Direction="Ascending"/>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ExternalBranchNumber" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The sorting is properly applied to the DataGrid but there is no indication of the sorting on the grid.

Looking at the view in the code behind I see the SortDescriptions in the collection and I've tried refreshing the view but it did not work.

How can I have the ColumnHeader arrows properly reflect the status of the view's SortDescription collection initially?

UPDATE:  I found an answer.  I added the SortDirection to the DataGridTextColumn in the DataGrid.  This added the ColumnHeader arrows.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Ext Firm #" Binding="{Binding ExternalOrgNo}" DisplayIndex="4" SortDirection="Ascending" Visibility="Visible" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Ext Branch #" Binding="{Binding ExternalBranchNumber}" DisplayIndex="5" SortDirection="Ascending" Visibility="Visible" />
```

Comment: As you've found the answer it's better that you post it as an answer and mark it as accepted (Yes, on SO you can answer yourself!)
This way anybody who comes across your question in future can more easily notice it's answered.

Answer (score 3):

The OP doesn't look like to be a regular visitor so until that moment I post his solution as an answer:

Add the [`SortDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the [`DataGridTextColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  in the [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This added the `ColumnHeader` arrows.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Ext Firm #" 
                    Binding="{Binding ExternalOrgNo}" 
                    DisplayIndex="4" 
                    SortDirection="Ascending" 
                    Visibility="Visible" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Ext Branch #" 
                    Binding="{Binding ExternalBranchNumber}" 
                    DisplayIndex="5" 
                    SortDirection="Ascending" 
                    Visibility="Visible" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the CollectionViewSource's `SortDescriptions` property is set in code and varies at runtime, so setting a constant `SortDescription="Ascending"` would be wrong because it wouldn't reflect the current sorting.