# WPF - DataGrid Default sorting does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid and I want it to be sorted based on the value of its first column. But this default sorting does not occur. But if I click on the header , then it gets sorted. First in ascending order , then in descending order.
I want default ordering to take place too. Can someone pls help me to resolve this ?

```
  <DataGrid ItemSource="........."
            CanUserSortColumns="True">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Headr="aaaa" SortMemberPath="MyValue" SortDirection="Ascending" CanUserSort="True">

         ................
          </DataGridTemplateColumn >

          <DataGridTemplateColumn  ........>
                 .........................
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>

          <DataGridTemplateColumn  ...........>
                 ........................
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>

  </DataGrid>
```

Comment: here is the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627149/pre-sorting-a-datagrid-in-wpf