# C# WPF Sorting DataGrid on XAML side

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I tried using the method documented in this thread:
[Pre-sorting a DataGrid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627149/pre-sorting-a-datagrid-in-wpf)

My issue however is that my datagrid's itemssource is not always the same...it will be bound to different observable collections during the execution of the program. With that, how do I sort the data grid? Is there another way to do this? on the display side....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data binding to set the ItemsSource then just add an IValueConverter (via the Converter property) that converts it to a CollectionView when it's set.  If you are using code to set your ItemsSource then just follow their example.

You won't be able to use XAML to populate the SortDescriptions on the CollectionView however, unless you write your own MarkupExtension or an attached property of some sort.  These are somewhat advanced topics so please indicate if that is the kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: This eventually worked for me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d3942c8-e3e1-4284-b1b3-0b8b94150d86/sort-wpf-datagrid-column-programmatically?forum=wpf           

I set the ItemsSource and programatically add the sortdescription. I'm not sure why I can't make it work within XAML...I can only get it to work in the C# side.

Also...I need to be able to edit the data after it's sorted...and this allows me to do that as well as change the ItemsSource.

Comment: You can't do it in vanilla XAML because it only modifies the original CollectionView object.  You can write an attached property that will do this for you however.